# Implementing TestSuite in NUnit

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I keep getting :

```
The type or namespace name 'TestSuite' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I use visual studio 2010 and I have installed the latest NUnit and selenium references via NuGet. Here is the code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    public class ManifestTestSuite
    {
        [Suite] 
        public static TestSuite Suite
        {
            get
            {
                TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("MyTestSuite");
                suite.Add(new AddAll());
                suite.Add(new RemoveAll());
                return suite;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TestSuite` class lives inside the `nunit.core.dll` which is not distributed with the  the nuget package because normally there is no need for it.

So you need to download the "full" nunit package from the [the NUnit website](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download) and you can find the `nunit.core.dll` in the lib folder inside the zip file.

However you don't need to this because there is a new approach since 2.4.4 as described in the [documenation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=suite&r=2.6.2): you can return an array of the tests instead of an instance `TestSuite`:

```
[Suite] 
public static IEnumerable Suite
{
    get
    {
        ArrayList suite = new ArrayList();
        suite.Add(new AddAll());
        suite.Add(new RemoveAll());
        return suite;
    }
}
```